# Remove textbox formatting

Tags: c#, format

I want to remove the text box formatting.

I format the textbox with following code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBSalary.Text))
            {
                CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                int valueBefore = Int32.Parse(txtBSalary.Text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                txtBSalary.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N}", valueBefore);
                txtBSalary.Select(txtBSalary.Text.Length, 0);
            }
```

And I try to undo the formatting with following code

```
int integerValue = Int32.Parse(txtBSalary.Text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

but I'm unable to get the integer value

Comment: Can you show sample text which might be in your textbox?

Comment: `I'm unable to get the integer value`explain what happens! Exception? Invalid result?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the raw value in the `TextBox.Tag` property, like this:

```
string originalSalaryValue = "123456";

txtBSalary.Tag = originalSalaryValue;
txtBSalary.Text = someFormattedVersionOfOriginalSalaryValue;
```

Now when you want to convert the value to a number, then you apply the `Int32.Parse()` to the `Tag` value, instead of the `Text` value, like this:

```
int integerValue = Int32.Parse(txtBSalary.Tag);
```

Read documentation for [Control.Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx).